# How do I change the text inside a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that uses Bootstrap, and a data grid created with KendoUI, and each row contains a button of the form...

```
<button type="button" id="requestbtn1" class="btn btn-success">Request</button>
```

I hooked up the click events of these buttons with the following Javascript...

```
$("button[id^='requestbtn']").click(function() {
  var lgid = String(this.id).replace("requestbtn", "");
  alert("Request for slip " + lgid);
  this.html("Done");
  this.addClass("btn-primary");
  this.removeClass("btn-success");
});
```

The code is called, and the alert displays the correct number, but I was trying to change the button's text to "Done" and the CSS class to "btn-primary" to remind the user that they have already made this request.

None of the last three lines work. I originally had them all in one line, like this...

```
  this.html("Done").addClass("btn-primary").removeClass("btn-success");
```

...but split them up to see if any would work independently.

Anyone have any idea how I can change the text and CSS class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$("button[id^='requestbtn']").click(function() {
  var lgid = String(this.id).replace("requestbtn", "");
  alert("Request for slip " + lgid);
  var $this = $(this);
  Sthis.html("Done");
  Sthis.addClass("btn-primary");
  Sthis.removeClass("btn-success");
});
```

Comment: Super fast and excellent reply! Please can you explain what the extra code does, I'm a little new to all this.

Comment: this gives you the DOM element, but not as a jQuery object. So you don;t get the methods that you want to use

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$(this).html(...` instead of assigning `$(this)` to a variable?

Comment: yes, but $(this) uses a lot of processing, so doing it 3 times is inefficient - hence creating the variable just once

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Didn't know that.

Comment: Presumably if I did $(this).html("Done").addClass("...").removeClass("...") then it would only process it once? Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call jQuery methods (`html()`, `addClass()`, `removeClass()` etc) on native DOM nodes (`this`); which has no access to such methods. If you're using jQuery, remember to use jQuery. Or, at the very least, remember whether you're using the DOM or jQuery.

Try:

```
$("button[id^='requestbtn']").click(function() {
  var lgid = String(this.id).replace("requestbtn", "");
  alert("Request for slip " + lgid);
  $(this).html("Done").addClass("btn-primary").removeClass("btn-success");
});
```

Or, use native DOM alternatives:

```
$("button[id^='requestbtn']").click(function() {
  var lgid = String(this.id).replace("requestbtn", "");
  alert("Request for slip " + lgid);
  this.innerHTML = 'Done';
  this.classList.add('btn-primary');
  this.classList.remove('btn-success');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, as you both gave essentially the same answer, I marked them both :)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have helped. :)

Comment: Was there a reason you felt you had to change your accepted answer, did my solution fail your requirements in some manner?

Comment: Not at all, it was excellent. Simon's reply came in first, and I marked it as an answer, then your updated reply came in, and I marked that as well. It was only afterwards that I realised that you can only mark one as an answer, and by marking yours as the answer, it unmarked Simon's. I felt that it was only fair that if only one could be the answer, his should be, as it came in first. Both replies were equally helpful, and if I could mark them both as an answer, I would. Sorry if you got the wrong impression.